# Obtener datos JSON de API Rest leído con Flutter sin usar Future

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, rest

Tengo un JSON en el que recibo un array con objetos "tienda" que se componen de número de tienda, localidad y provincia de la misma. Querría utilizar toda esa información del array para crear, a su vez, un array de provincias y localidades. Pero la única manera que conozco para acceder a un array en Flutter es a través de la clase FutureBuilder que "obliga" a retornar un Widget. Yo quiero poder "operar" con el array recibido por API, pero no lo consigo.

Resumiendo: ¿cómo puedo crear un array de provincias extrayendo del array de tiendas las provincias donde se encuentran las mismas?

Muchas gracias.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ShopSelectScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShopSelectScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ShopSelectScreen> createState() => _ShopSelectScreenState();
}

String urlBotigues =
    'https://....';
String urlProvincies =
    ' https://....';
String token = '....';

http.Client client = http.Client();
late Future<List<Shop>> shops;
late Future<List<String>> provincias;
late Future<List<String>> localidades;

Future<List<Shop>> fetchShop() async {
  final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(urlBotigues), headers: {
    'AUTH-COM': token,
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    //"Accept": "application/json",
  });

  return (jsonDecode(const Utf8Decoder().convert(response.body.codeUnits))
      .map<Shop>((json) => Shop.fromJson(json))
      .toList());
}


class _ShopSelectScreenState extends State<ShopSelectScreen> {
  late Future<List<Shop>> tiendas;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tiendas = fetchShop();
    //Obtener las distintas provincias de las tiendas
    //Obtener localidades
    //Obtener tiendas segun provincias y localidades
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Escoger tiendas')),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            //Provincies
            /* SizedBox(
              height: 300,
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: provincias,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ProvinciaChips(provincias: snapshot.data!);
                  }
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Text('Ha ocurrido un error con el servidor');
                  } else {
                    return const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ), */
            //Localitats
            //Botigues
            SizedBox(
              height: 300,
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: tiendas,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ShopChips(shops: snapshot.data!);
                  }
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Text('Ha ocurrido un error con el servidor');
                  } else {
                    return const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class ProvinciaChips extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProvinciaChips({super.key, required this.provincies});

  final List<String> provincies;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: provincies.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Chip(
          label: Text(provincies[index]),
        );
      },
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 6, childAspectRatio: 0.5),
    );
  }
}

class ShopChips extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShopChips({super.key, required this.shops});

  final List<Shop> shops;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: shops.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Chip(
          label: Text(shops[index].nomBotiga),
        );
      },
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 12, childAspectRatio: 0.5),
    );
  }
}

class Shop {
  final dynamic activa;
  final dynamic direccio;
  final dynamic id;
  final dynamic latitud;
  final dynamic longitud;
  final dynamic nomBotiga;
  final dynamic numero;
  final dynamic poblacio;
  final dynamic provincia;
  final dynamic serveiPrimeraHora;
  final dynamic telf;
  final dynamic tipus;

  Shop({
    required this.activa,
    required this.direccio,
    required this.id,
    required this.latitud,
    required this.longitud,
    required this.nomBotiga,
    required this.numero,
    required this.poblacio,
    required this.provincia,
    required this.serveiPrimeraHora,
    required this.telf,
    required this.tipus,
  });

  factory Shop.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Shop(
      activa: json['activa'],
      direccio: json['direccio'],
      id: json['id'],
      latitud: json['latitud'],
      longitud: json['longitud'],
      nomBotiga: json['nomBotiga'],
      numero: json['numero'],
      poblacio: json['poblacio'],
      provincia: json['provincia'],
      serveiPrimeraHora: json['serveiPrimeraHora'],
      telf: json['telf'],
      tipus: json['tipus'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Reformula la pregunta, a ver si así tienes más suerte y alguien te responde.

Comment: Basado en los pocos datos , y en como se formula pregunta ,Tendrías que crear un modelo, del endpoint que deseas consumir, posteriormente, convertir las respuesta json a formato dart, y ya simplemente vas consumiendo los datos, con la ayuda de GetX.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he reformulado la pregunta para ver si así se entiende mejor. Continuo buscando soluciones

Comment: Buenas, desconozco esa librería. De momento ya me funciona gracias a la solución indicada como correcta, pero me apunto esa librería para futuros requerimientos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responder esta pregunta se hace complicado porque hay que explicar muchos conceptos. Tu problema no radica en usar FutureBuilder, sino en como estructurar tus consultas, tus clases, tus widgets, etc., para separar la lógica de la representación en widgets de la misma.

Hay un concepto llamado `Clean Arquitecture` que se usa mucho en el desarrollo de aplicaciones, de todo tipo, y en Flutter funciona muy bien.

En resumen, este concepto te explica como separar el código en capas/módulos y como conectarlos entre sí.

También, en Flutter hay otro concepto importante inherente al framework, la gestión de estado. Lo más normal, es usar paquetes externos (librerías) para dicha gestión.

Tú lo estás haciendo con StatefullWidget, lo cual, no está mal, pero es una locura y casi imposible de utilizar para proyectos reales. Como gestores de estados, te podría recomendar `Provider`, `GetX`, `Bloc`, o `Riverpod`. Están ordenados por dificultad de aprendizaje, siendo `Provider` el más fácil.

Ahora bien, retomando tu pregunta, tu problema radica en que tienes tu lógica, la llamada a tu endpoint para obtener los datos, en un método de la vista, que además, se está usando en el FutureBuilder, lo que te quita bastante control sobre cómo y dónde usarlo.

Una solución óptima, sería aplicar los conceptos de los que te hablo más arriba, pero como son algo más complicado de explicar, te dejo una solución más adaptada a cómo estas programando.

Primero, la explicación del proceso.

Dices que la única forma que tienes de acceder a un array es con un `FutureBuilder`, lo cual está mal dicho, pues lo correcto sería decir, que la única forma en la cual sabes **acceder a una operación asíncrona** es con un `FutureBuilder`.

Aquí se da el problema de que tenemos que obtener los datos asíncronamente haciendo una petición a un endpoint y luego, reaccionar según si vienen o no datos. El `FutureBuilder` no es más que un `StatefullWidget` que te encapsula ese proceso, en tu caso, lo mejor sería utilizar un `StatefullWidget` directamente.

El `state` de un `StatefullWidget` tiene un método llamado `initState`, el cual se ejecuta antes de pintar nada, antes de ejecutar el método `build`. Lo ideal sería tener algunas variables de bandera para saber en qué estado estamos.

```dart
class ShopPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShopPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShopPage> createState() => _ShopPageState();
}

class _ShopPageState extends State<ShopPage> {
  var _isLoaded = false;
  Shop? _shopList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Shop')),
      body: _isLoaded
          ? ShopView(_shopList)
          : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _loadData() async {
    final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(urlBotigues), headers: {
      'AUTH-COM': token,
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      //"Accept": "application/json",
    });
  }

  Future<void> fetchShop() async {
    final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(urlBotigues), headers: {
      'AUTH-COM': token,
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      //"Accept": "application/json",
    });

    final shopList =
        jsonDecode(const Utf8Decoder().convert(response.body.codeUnits))
            .map<Shop>((json) => Shop.fromJson(json))
            .toList();

    // Teniendo la lista de shops, puedes obtener las provincias
    // o cualquier otro dato que necesites.

    setState(() {
      _shopList = shopList;
      _isLoaded = true;
    });
  }
}
```

Ya no hay necesidad de usar `FutureBuilder` y los datos obtenido de la función `fetchShop`, son almacenados dentro del `state`, por lo cual los tenemos accesibles para enviarlos a otros Widgets.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación, finalmente ha funcionado y he entendido un poco  más el funcionamiento de los accesos a las API y las funciones asíncronas.
Debo comentar que el código está todo unido y sin separar por responsabilidades porque no sabía como presentar distintos archivos en la publicación. 

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Quizás te podría servir este ejemplo como referencia. ***responseData*** es un arreglo de objetos el cual contiene *Clave_Carrera* y *Nombre* de la carrera, después se agrega a una lista de tipo clase (Carrera y Nombres) o en tu situación de tipo *String*.

```
  try {
    String url = '$baseUrl/Carreras';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var responseData = json.decode(response.body);
    List<Nombres> listNombres = [];
    List<Carrera> listCarreras = [];

    for (var item in responseData) {
      Nombres nombre = Nombres(nombre: item['Nombre']);
      listNombres.add(nombre);

      Carrera carrera = Carrera(claveCarrera: item['Clave_Carrera']);
      listCarreras.add(carrera);
    }
    return listCarreras;
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Error');
  }
```

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias, antes de la solución que he indicado como correcta debo decirte que la tuya no me funcionó. Pero estoy muy agradecido por su ayuda.